# parse complete json and search keys matching a value

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I want to traverse whole JSON in javascript and find the values starting a particular key.
Suppose this is my JSON data:

```
var data = {
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "abc":{
      "mohit_ab": {
        "id1":"i am id 1",
        "abcd":{
          "a" :"b",
          "c":"d"
        },
        "who" : "who are you",
        "id2":"i am id 2"
      },
      "mohit_231abcd": {
        "id1":"i am id 3",
        "identity" : "i am real mohit",
        "id2":"i am id 4"
      }
    },
    "hji":{
      "mohit_adss231": {
        "id1":"i am id 5",
        "identity" : "i am mohit in real",
        "id2":"i am id 6"
      },
      "mohit": {
        "id7":"i am id 7",
        "identity" : "i am mohit and you?",
        "id8":"i am id 8"
      }
    },
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
};
```

I want to parse complete JSON in javascript and get the values whose key starts with "mohit". e.g. output of above input is :

```
valueableData:{
  "mohit_ab": {
        "id1":"i am id 1",
        "abcd":{
          "a" :"b",
          "c":"d"
        },
        "who" : "who are you",
        "id2":"i am id 2"
      },
      "mohit_231abcd": {
        "id1":"i am id 3",
        "identity" : "i am real mohit",
        "id2":"i am id 4"
      },
      "mohit_adss231": {
        "id1":"i am id 5",
        "identity" : "i am mohit in real",
        "id2":"i am id 6"
      },
      "mohit": {
        "id7":"i am id 7",
        "identity" : "i am mohit and you?",
        "id8":"i am id 8"
      }
}
```

Please suggest me the easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive approach you used in your own answer is a good general solution, always functional.
But it's fully traversing the source object, so in case of a huge number of nested sub-objects it may impact performance.

With the solution below, the whole source object is also fully traversed, but the work is made by JS internals, which is faster.
More over, the code is slighter and more readable.

```js
var data = {
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "abc":{
      "mohit_ab": {
        "id1":"i am id 1",
        "abcd":{
          "a" :"b",
          "c":"d"
        },
        "who" : "who are you",
        "id2":"i am id 2"
      },
      "mohit_231abcd": {
        "id1":"i am id 3",
        "identity" : "i am real mohit",
        "id2":"i am id 4"
      }
    },
    "hji":{
      "mohit_adss231": {
        "id1":"i am id 5",
        "identity" : "i am mohit in real",
        "id2":"i am id 6"
      },
      "mohit": {
        "id7":"i am id 7",
        "identity" : "i am mohit and you?",
        "id8":"i am id 8"
      }
    },
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
};

var valuableData = {};
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), function(key, value) {
  if (key.substr(0, 5) == 'mohit') {
    valuableData[key] = value;
  }
  return value;
});

document.write('ValuableData:');
for (var key in valuableData) {
  document.write('<br />' + key + ': ' + JSON.stringify(valuableData[key]));
}
```

Here is it, with explanatory comments:

```
var valuableData = {};
// use JSON.parse, not to get its result but only to benefit of its "reviver" function
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), function(key, value) {
  // when encoutering one of the keys we're looking for, populate our own result
  if (key.substr(0, 5) == 'mohit') {
    valuableData[key] = value;
  }
  // in any case, don't break the normal generation of the JSON.parse result
  // (or the keys we select above would have been left empty!)
  return value;
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I am new to javascript can you tell me the how can search iterate in data to get values of these keys?

Comment: @MohitJain Uh... Sorry, I was to complete my answer in response to your comment when I realized I was wrong the same way than the other answerer; didn't pay attention to the different levels. So currently my answer doesn't help! Nevertheless I find this question really interesting, so I'll try to give a functional answer... but only tomorrow, because at the moment it's 5AM for me :)

Comment: Sure No issues. Please try it and give me the answer when you get time. Thanks..:-)

Comment: I answered my question, please verify it.

Comment: @MohitJain From your original question I imagined you thought you'd already get a recursive approach but were looking for something more concise: it's why I posted my first answer, but that was wrong. I actually ended with a (IMO) good one: look at my edited answer. Regarding your own answer, look at my comment under it.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your solution, it seems interesting the way you used JSON.parse function. I believe your solution will be faster. But, is there any way to test performance of both the solutions ?

Comment: @MohitJain The simpler way to test performance is using `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Timers. Caution: to get reliable results, _keep any console.log`()` and other outputs outside_ of the time/timeEnd interval!

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for this :

```
var valueAbleData = {};
  this.add = function(value) {
      for (var key in value){
            if(key.indexOf("mohit") > -1){
                valueAbleData[key] =  value[key];
            }
            else if(value[key] !== null && typeof value[key] === 'object'){
                this.add(value[key]);
            }
            }
    };
```

If anyone can provide better answer then please post it. :)

Comment: As stated in my own answer I agree that this is a good approach (using recursion is always an ultimate solution for almost everything), but may be harmful if applied to a big source data. So when another one is available, it's better. Here I only notice two points: 1) Apart if I'm missing something subtle, I don't understand your `this`: you might merely have `function add(value)`; 2) with `key.indexOf('mohit') > -1` you'll select keys such as `foobar-mohit` as well! So you'd better doing `== 0`.

Comment: For the answer of your 2 points : 1) This is just demo function on local system, add(value) and this. I will change it after finalising my answer. 2) Thanks for the indexof('mohit'), I will change it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a **for loop**

```
var results = [];
for (var key in valueableData)
{
    if ( key.indexOf("mohit") == 0 )
      results.push(valueableData[key]);
}
```

**results** array will contain the matched objects.

Comment: This approach can only work when we have data at same level, but my data is hierarchical. It will loop on top levels only.